# How to reload a collectionview cell without reloading an image

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view and when something changes I update the data source and reload the cell in which the change occurs.  The cell kind of blinks when it reloads.  It doesn't really affect the user scrolling and I made it almost unnoticeable with:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation{
     self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)])
}
```

This was the best I could do to make the reload less noticeable.  I have a background image taking up the entire cell.  I think the flash that I'm seeing is this image reloading, yet I don't need it to reload because the image will never change.  Does anyone know how to make the cell reload but not the image?  I can put a variable in there and change it such as (initalLoad = false) but I don't know how to keep the image from reloading.

Comment: Where does the image come from? Is it part of the nib, or do you load it somewhere in 'cellForItemAtIndex"?

Comment: It's loaded in the custom cell class from the data source (from url) or from cache if it has been cached (using pincache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving all your cell setup to an internal func in your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var initialLoad = true

    // since collection view cells are recycled for memory efficiency,
    // you'll have to reset the initialLoad variable before a cell is reused
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        initialLoad = true
    }

    internal func configureCell() {

        if initialLoad {
            // set your image here
        }

        initialLoad = false

        // do everything else here
    }

}
```

and then calling it from your view controller:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.configureCell()
    return cell
}
```

You can add parameters to the `configureCell()` function to pass in any data you need for setting up the cell (presumably you'll need to pass in some kind of reference to your image). If you have a lot of information, you might want to create a custom object to hold all that information, then pass that into the function as a parameter.

Comment: Yeah I was working on something like this but ran into complications with the layout because i'm using asyncdisplaykit, but I still think it'll work just have to modify the layout a lot, will come back afterwards to mark as correct as long as it works okay which I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: I was kind of worried about it just not having an image.  I wasn't sure if it would keep the image from the original, or just not have one at all after reload.

Comment: If it doesn't work with your setup for some reason, edit your question with the relevant code and issues and I'll take a look.